# Circular dependency warning angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-cli, warnings, circular-dependency

I am struggling to solve the circular dependency warning when building an angular 5 app.

I have read these two questions: the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466147/warning-in-circular-dependency-detected-angular-cli?rq=1)  and the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113734/angular-4-circular-dependency-detected), but can't figure out the problem in my code and how to solve it.

here is the warning:

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\pages\addresses\add-address\add-address.component.ngfactory.js -> src\pages\nav-bar\nav-bar.component.ngfactory.js -> src\pages\cart-panel\cart-panel.component.ngfactory.js -> src\pages\addresses\add-address\add-address.component.ngfactory.js
```

I am using the service-provider as a service that other components are using.

**add-address.component.ts**

```
import { ServiceProvider} from '../../../providers/service-provider';
import { AlertService } from '../../../providers/alert-provider';
```

**nav-bar.component.ts**

```
import { ServiceProvider} from '../../providers/service-provider';
import { AlertService } from '../../providers/alert-provider';
```

**cart-panel-component.ts**

```
import { ServiceProvider} from '../../providers/service-provider';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<add-address></add-address>` component inner html uses `<nav-bar></nav-bar>` that inner html use the component `<cart-panel></cart-panel>` the component inner html uses `<add-address></add-address>` and this will cause the loop, so the circle will never be closed, so remove from cart-panel-component the add-address tag and the code will compile.

**Example Rendered Angular HTML:**

```
   <add-address>
     <nav-bar>
       <cart-panel>
        <!-- cause circle -->
        <add-address><!-- remove this in the add-address component -->
          <!-- add-address > nav-bar > cart-panel > add-address..... -->
        </add-address>
       </cart-panel>
     </nav-bar>
   </add-address>
```